# How to group elements by row?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Hi I just started to learn d3.js and I have a problem, how do I group every row together?

Lets assume that I have that simple array and I want to create 2 groups the first group contains the elements at 0,1 position and the second group contains the elements at 2,3 position.

```
var svgViewport = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000);

let myData = [{
    x: 30,
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: 50,
    y: 70
  },
  {
    x: 70,
    y: 80
  },
  {
    x: 90,
    y: 90
  }
];

var circleSelect = svgViewport.selectAll("circle").data(myData);

var circles = circleSelect.enter().append("circle");

circles
  .attr("cx", (d) => {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", (d) => {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", 10);
```

I also tried to give each one a class but in this case I am having a problem selecting by class name

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    svgViewport.append("g")
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **do not** use a `for` loop to append elements in a D3 code. We do use `for` loops (and similar methods), but in very specific situations. Explaining how to refactor your second snippet requires a new answer (here at S.O. we keep just 1 issue per post).

If I understand your question correctly, by *group* you mean `<g>` elements. In that case, you should separate the data (in inner arrays) according to the desired groups. For instance:

```
let myData=[[{x:30,y:40},{x:50,y:70}],
    [{x:70,y:80},{x:90,y:90}]
];
```

And here is a demo, *using only enter selections*:

```js
const svgViewport = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150);

let myData = [
  [{
      x: 30,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 50,
      y: 70
    }
  ],
  [{
      x: 70,
      y: 80
    },
    {
      x: 90,
      y: 90
    }
  ]
];

const groups = svgViewport.selectAll(null)
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

const circles = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(d => d)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("cy", (d) => d.y)
  .attr("r", 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This generates the following structure:

```
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <g>
    <circle cx="30" cy="40" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="50" cy="70" r="10"></circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <circle cx="70" cy="80" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="10"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```